# ajax doesn't pass array of objects to action

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax, frombodyattribute

I am using ajax to pass Json data to an action in an asp.net core project.
I have an array of objects to pass

```
  var AgentScores = [];
.
.
.
AgentScores.push({
  AgentId: AgentId,
  Fullname: Fullname,
  Score : Score
            });
```

```
  $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Score/SelfReportedScores",
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                      
                        //large data must be passed using json
                        data: JSON.stringify(AgentScores),
                    
                        success: function (result) {
                     
                        },
                        error: function (e) {
                        }
                    });
```

I have a class called AgentsListScoreClass.cs and below is how I am trying to get the array in my action:

```
 public void SelfReportedScores([FromBody] List<AgentsListScoreClass> AgentScores)
        {
```

`AgentScores`  is always null.
It is ok when I pass a List of string, but with `AgentsListScoreClass` it is always null.

```
public class AgentsListScoreClass
{
    public string AgentId { get; set; }
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    public short Score { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AgentScores  is always null.

Please capture the actual request with posted data in browser developer tool Network tab, and check if the data you posted look like below.

[image]

And the property `AgentId` of your `AgentsListScoreClass` model is defined as `string` type, please make sure you wrap the value with quotes, like this `"AgentId":"1"`.

***Update:***

> `AgentScores.push({AgentId: AgentId, Fullname: Fullname, Score : Score});`

> this is how data looks like 'data = "[{"AgentId":"015d6fce-2b6e-4702-b4ac-8af31bba8ffa","Fullname":"name","Score":"0"},{"AgentId":" ......'

You can try to use `parseFloat()` function to parse `Score` data, like below.

```
AgentScores.push({
    AgentId: AgentId,
    Fullname: Fullname,
    Score: parseFloat(Score)
});
```

Comment: this is how data looks like
'data = "[{\"AgentId\":\"015d6fce-2b6e-4702-b4ac-8af31bba8ffa\",\"Fullname\":\"name\",\"Score\":\"0\"},{\"AgentId\":\" ......'

Comment: `\"Score\":\"0\"` you can try to use `parseFloat()` function to parse Score data first, and you can check my update.

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix ajax bugs by removing  contenttype and stringify

```
  var agentScores = [];

agentScores.push(
{
  AgentId: AgentId,
  Fullname: Fullname,
  Score : Score
   }
);
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
   url: "/Score/SelfReportedScores",
   data: { agentScores },
    success: function (result) {
  },
error: function (e) {
 }
 });
```

And maybe you need [FromBody] only for a Postman. Try to remove it if you still have null.